# Hbase bulk upload issue - standalone mode

Tags: hbase, bulkinsert, ubuntu-12.04

I am very new to Hbase. I am using Hbase in standalone mode and developing application using google n-grams. I am using a ubuntu box in Amazon Ec2 instance

I am doing 1Million writes using my program through batch api.

```
        HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName);
        conf.set("zookeeper.session.timeout", "180000");
        conf.set("hbase.rpc.timeout", "180000");
        conf.set("hbase.regionserver.logroll.period", "180000");
        conf.set("hbase.hregion.max.filesize","51200");
        table.setAutoFlush(false);
        table.batch(iterateList);
        table.flushCommits();
```

When I execute this with 1M rows, I am getting the following exceptions in the below order,

```
    12/08/28 14:17:13 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x1396d9653bd0004, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
    12/08/28 14:17:13 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x1396d9653bd0003, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
    12/08/28 14:17:13 WARN client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Failed all from region=googlegrams,,1346160551634.abc8baf335dee8485d64a6c8b989d6b0., hostname=ip-10-80-74-132.ec2.internal, port=45549
```

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Call to ip-10-80-74-132.ec2.internal/10.80.74.132:45549 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException

and then

```
  12/08/28 14:17:15 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x1396d9653bd0004
  for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:701)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:286)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1035)
```

few things I tried are,
1. Changes for ulimit and nproc settings for ubuntu
2. Hbase configuration like zookeeper timeout, rpc timeout logroll period and hregion fileSize

Please help!

Cheers,
Dwarak

Answer (score 1):

try increasing hbase.client.lease.period